# BigQuery API communication public internet/google intranet

Tags: api, google-bigquery, google-compute-engine

I am using BiGQuery API from Google compute node (in a DataFlow job). My dataflow compute engine is inside a VPC. I am calling some SQL commands on a dataset in our project. I understand that BIgQuery and GCS buckets won't be within our VPC. However, I couldn't find any documentation how API calls are routed. Will they be routed using public internet or will it be going through google private intranet (As origination of call is within compute node).

Answer (score 3):

Google api is indeed over public secure ssl Internet connection (port 443).
Main end point url is: https://bigquery.googleapis.com

You can test and play with BigQuery api from this url: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query

After running a query you can see all the http parameters used.